# Understanding awk command

Tags: awk, gawk

I need help in understanding the following awk command

```
awk -F "<name>|</name>|<machine>|</machine>" '{if($0 ~ "<name>" && $0 ~ "</name>") nm=$2;else if($0 ~ "<machine>" && $0 ~ "</machine>") {print nm,$2}}' config.xml
```

This command is giving me the output of weblogic managed servers and their respective hosts in the following format.

```
managed_server1 host1
managed_server2 host2
managed_server3 host3
```

Comment: Have you tried to understand it? What pieces, specifically, are you confused by?

Comment: Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and it'll be crystal clear.

Comment: Hi Etan,
I tried but invain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly well written script but extracts values from lines in this format (and in this order)

```
<name>xxx</name>
<machine>yyy</machine>
```

and outputs

```
xxx yyy
```

Sets the field delimiter to open/close xml tags and if the first pair is present in the line sets a variable to the value from the second field and when the second pair is present print the previous value set and current second field.

Comment: Can you help me understanding it by giving me a breakdown?

Comment: Thanks karakfa, but I'm looking for more breakdown.

Comment: "Sets the field delimiter to open/close xml tags and if the first pair is present in the line sets a variable to the value from the second field and when the second pair is present print the previous value set and current second field." is not enough?